# Append Color Values to Query Results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query:

```sql
declare @colors table (color varchar(50));
declare @T table(RowNo int, LocationID bigint, TotalSales money, DBAName varchar(50), Color varchar(50));

insert into @colors
select distinct Color
from dbx.dbo.SampleData;

select top 5 *
from @colors
order by newid()

insert into @T
select (row_number() over (order by LocationID)) as RowNo,
        LocationID, sum(TransAmount) as TotalSales, DBAName, Color
from dbx.dbo.SampleData
group by LocationID, DBAName, Color

select * from (
  select LocationID, TotalSales, DBAName
  from @T
) x
group by LocationID, TotalSales, DBAName
```

Which has these results:

[image: Results]

I want to know how to `RIGHT JOIN` (or whatever other better solution) `@colors` onto `@T` so that each row has a unique color value like so:

[image: What I want]

I appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: And what color should the rows have?. How do we choose the right color for every row?

Comment: The colors are pulled in the query. Check the pictures. There are two tables that I create. One has color values, the other has data.

Comment: Yeah, I can check it now that you edited your question with new pictures that include that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have some common column in the two tables to join them. For example you can have an additional column in the Colors table called LocationId and assign unique color to each locationId. Then the query will be:

```sql
Select T.LocationID, T.TotalSales, T.DBAName,C.Color
From @T t join @Colors C on T.LocationId=C.LocationId
```